# Select multiple items which match mapping table more then once

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to select questions which have a certain topic id. These matches are stored in a mapping table, but I cannot work out how to select questions that have two tags to them seeing as they are stored as different rows in the table! Any help, please?

```
SELECT questions. * , posts.post, posts.id AS post_id, posts.created, users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.rep
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN posts ON questions.id = posts.question_id
LEFT JOIN users ON questions.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN topic_mapping ON questions.id = topic_mapping.question_id
WHERE topic_mapping.topic_id =49
OR topic_mapping.topic_id =50
GROUP BY questions.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find questions that have *both* topics assigned, test the number of distinct topics found in a HAVING clause. This number should match the number of topics you've included in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT questions. * , posts.post, posts.id AS post_id, posts.created, users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.rep
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN posts ON questions.id = posts.question_id
LEFT JOIN users ON questions.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN topic_mapping ON questions.id = topic_mapping.question_id
WHERE topic_mapping.topic_id IN (49,50)
GROUP BY questions.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT topic_mapping.topic_id) = 2
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain me just a bit what IN does, i assume it is like an equality check. And why does that HAVING buisness solve the problem. But your code does work though!!

Comment: IN is just a syntactic shorthand for multiple OR statements. The HAVING business guarantees that the number of distinct topics found, 2 in your example, matches the number enumerated in the IN list.

Comment: Thanks Joe! One last question, why when I leave out DISTINCT does it return only questions with have only one of the tags? And why when I leave out HAVING does it not work and return questions with one tag? Will accept in a minute

Comment: The DISTINCT depends on your data. If you have the DB set up so that each topic can only be associated with a question once (e.g., a unique index on question_id and topic_id in the topic_mapping table), then you don't need it. If you leave out the HAVING all together, you'd get questions that had *either* topic assigned, not necessarily questions that have *both* topics assigned.

Comment: Yeah, but why? Sorry to be a bother, but what does having tell the query in plain english

Comment: HAVING is used when you need to test the results of an aggregate function. In this particular case, the aggregate function is the COUNT. In plain english, we're saying that the questions found must have *both* topics assigned.

Answer (score 1):

To get the question IDs, use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
  questions.id
FROM questions LEFT JOIN topic_mapping ON questions.user_id = topic_mapping.question_id
WHERE topic_id = 49 OR topic_id = 50
GROUP BY questions.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT topic_id) = 2
```

The result of this is a list of question ids that can then be joined against the rest of your query on `questions.id` to retrieve the remaining columns not include in the `GROUP BY`. So the full thing looks like:

```
SELECT 
  questions.* , 
  posts.post,
  posts.id AS post_id,
  posts.created, 
  users.id AS user_id,
  users.username, 
  users.rep
FROM questions
JOIN (
    /* subquery gets the posts with 2 topics */
    SELECT
      questions.id
    FROM questions LEFT JOIN topic_mapping ON questions.user_id = topic_mapping.question_id
    WHERE topic_id = 49 OR topic_id = 50
    GROUP BY questions.id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT topic_id) = 2
) qtopics ON questions.id = qtopics.id
LEFT JOIN posts ON questions.id = posts.question_id
LEFT JOIN users ON questions.user_id = users.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I dont quite understand, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @youngcouple10 See my addition above.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but it wont return me any results!

Comment: Then I maybe misunderstood your requirement. Stick with @joestefanelli 's answer if it works for you

Comment: @youngcouple10 LOL, neither Joe nor I need the rep points. And he knows his stuff in MySQL.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the compliment and, if you ever figure out where we cash in all these rep points, let me know. :-)

Comment: @JoeStefanelli ...Or at least to be able to trade in [these](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/123/mysql) for a free one of [these](http://www.nerdmeritbadges.com/products/stack-overflow-gold)